# Add category links?

Tags: categories

Hi i’ve been trying to add category links as per the image attached. [image]
with categories ‘music’ ‘thoughts’ ‘products’ just below my banner. but i have no idea how to do it. is there a fast way of going about doing this?

https://thefussy.co/ and https://thefussy.co/category/thefword/ are the links where i hope the categories will display as well as all the sub categories from /thefword which are music,thoughts and products. i’ve tried editing the category.php file but i cant seem to make the categories appear. am i doing something wrong?

```
<?php if ( is_home ) : ?>
<div class="category-list-home">

<ul>

<?php 
    $args = array(
  'show_option_all'    => '',
  'orderby'            => 'name',
  'order'              => 'ASC',
  'style'              => 'list',
  'show_count'         => 0,
  'hide_empty'         => 1,
  'child_of'           => 14,
  'exclude'            => '',
  'exclude_tree'       => '',
  'include'            => '',
  'number'             => null,
  'echo'               => 1,
  'current_category'   => 0,
  'taxonomy'           => 'category',
    );
    wp_list_categories( $args ); 
?>
</ul>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

i tried placing the above code under my _index.php file.. which is showing fine with a little css i can make it how i want it to be like. but i cant seem to have the categories show up on the other subcategory pages like music, products or thoughts.

site: thefussy.co

Comment: Do you say that you have trid? Show us what have you tried, working or not.

Comment: <?php if ( is_home ) : ?>
<div class="category-list-home">
<ul>
<?php 
    $args = array(
  'show_option_all'    => '',
  'orderby'            => 'name',
  'order'              => 'ASC',
  'style'              => 'list',
  'show_count'         => 0,
  'hide_empty'         => 1,
  'child_of'           => 14,
  'exclude'            => '',
  'exclude_tree'       => '',
  'include'            => '',
  'number'             => null,
  'echo'               => 1,
  'current_category'   => 0,
  'taxonomy'           => 'category',
    );
    wp_list_categories( $args ); 
?>
</ul>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>

Comment: i tried placing the above code under my _index.php file.. which is showing fine with a little css i can make it how i want it to be like. but i cant seem to have the categories show up on the other subcategory pages like music, products or thoughts.

Comment: Please, add that code (and any other you may think is relevant) to the question. It is very difficult to read it in the comments.

Comment: yup added it in the question let me know if it's clearer? thanks

Answer (score 0):

> i tried placing the above code under my _index.php file.. which is
>   showing fine with a little css i can make it how i want it to be like.
>   but i cant seem to have the categories show up on the other
>   subcategory pages like music, products or thoughts.

If you managed to get it to work on your index in _index.php, maybe try _archive.php for category/tag index pages :)

edit: also drop that if(is_home)/endif of course, because category/tag pages are not home page!

Comment: cool! removing the if(is_home) settles the problem actually. interesting.. thanks alot guys!